# Error keeps occurring while doing npm run deploy

Tags: node.js, npm

When I try `npm run deploy`, Error occured.
I can't understand error message...
How can I resolve this problem??

```
> habit-tracker@0.1.0 deploy
> gh-pages -d build

Failed to get remote.origin.url (task must either be run in a git repository with a configured origin remote or must be configured with the "repo" option).
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\me\react_projects\react-basic\habit-tracker
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c gh-pages -d build

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-03-22T06_15_37_037Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Have you tried the solution(s) in the comments for [issue #192](https://github.com/tschaub/gh-pages/issues/192) ?

Comment: thx your opinion!